# How to get a basic script to run on startup

Tags: command-line, scripts

I've created a basic script for me to input into Terminal every time I restart my computer so it'll update the repositories, upgrade the apps, and then fix my external monitor resolution. It looks like this:

```
##This updates your repositories

sudo apt-get update

##This upgrades your applications

sudo apt-get upgrade

##This fixes your external monitor resolution

sudo cvt 1920 1080 60

sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Problem is I'm lazy as hell and pressing Ctrl+Alt+T to open up the Terminal and then type in 12 characters and press Enter is hard work, plus my parents use it and I doubt their capacity to follow the basic instructions I wrote out so they could do it themselves.

I tried Googling for the answer, but my Google-Fu is lacking.

So if anyone could help me automate my script to run at startup, at least the fixing monitor part, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It might be better to look at [unattended upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) for the first part of your script.

Comment: I still don't see you outputting the resolution.  Look at my script below.  You need an xrandr --output . . .

Answer (score 8):

To run your script at startup simply create a new cronjob. First open crontab by:

```
crontab -e
```

And then add the following line to it:

```
@reboot /path/to/your/script
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to comment out all the lines that are not scripts.

```
#this is a comment
sudo apt-get your command
```

Also this will fail becaue you need a yes.

```
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

That will say yes for you.  RISKY!

You don't need sudo to work with xrandr.

And you are never outputting your resolution. Here is an example of one of mine.

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1368x768_60.00" && xrandr --output VGA1 --mode  1368x768_60.00
```

the && runs the scripts on after another waiting (& does not wait) for the previous one to finish. Separate lines are fine as well.

I work in Kubuntu so in Settings under Startup and Shutdown I can point to that script and have it run at startup.

Comment: To be fair the comments on my script are used with ## so in terminal they don't show up, I just see them in gedit.

So if I add && to my xrandr part it will still work the same?

Comment: So I tried your way, it now looks like:


## This updates your repositories
sudo apt-get update


## This upgrades your applications
sudo apt-get -y upgrade


## This fixes your external monitor resolution
cvt 1920 1080 60 && xrandr  --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync &&xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1920x1080_60.00".

I then put it under the startup apps in Ubuntu Gnome, it worked, but my screen half freaked out on me first.

Comment: Very common to get some flickers and such when xrandr is adjusting.